# Filter multiple Crossfilter datasets

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

i am trying to set up a dashboard using two datasets, using this [Apply Filter from one Crossfilter dataset to another Crossfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225364/apply-filter-from-one-crossfilter-dataset-to-another-crossfilter#) as an example.  i've implemented this function

```
function mirror_dimension() {
  var dims = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

  function mirror(fname) {
    return function(v) {
      dims.forEach(function(dim) {
        dim[fname](v);
      });
    };
  }
  return {
    filter: mirror('filter'),
    filterExact: mirror('filterExact'),
    filterRange: mirror('filterRange'),
    filterFunction: mirror('filterFunction')
  };
}
```

and referenced it in my charts like this

```
  .dimension(mirror_dimension(k_yearDimension, p_mirror_year))
```

i've been able to display charts for each of them but the do not reset back to their original state when trying to reset or selecting and de-selecting rows on my charts.

my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/santoshsewlal/txrLw9Lc/

am i calling the mirror_dimension function incorrectly, or do i need to re-work it?

thanks

Comment: Your `reduceRemove` function is wrong. You are adding to `totalPoints` rather than subtracting. I think that's the problem?

Comment: d-oh!!!  thanks @EthanJewett.  Spent an hour looking at the wrong function